# Accessing logged in user in Symfony2 action and template

Tags: symfony

I am using Doctrine as Auth provider in my symfony2 app. How can I access authenticated user in action or template?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In your templates, you can do:

```
{{ app.user }}
```

And in your controller, if you extend the base controller provided by the framework bundle, you can do:

```
$this->getUser();
```

Anyway, you can access it from the service container:

```
$securityContext = $container->get('security.context');
$token = $securityContext->getToken();
$user = $token->getUser();
```

Comment: BTW, use `$this->container->get('security.authorization_checker')` instead (new in 2.6)

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old, but in case anyone is wondering, you can get the user in a template that uses the PHP Engine with

```
    $app->getUser();
```